# 階層の異なる301リダイレクト

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, .htaccess

## 実現したいこと

階層の異なる301リダイレクトを設定したいのですが、うまくいきません。よろしくお願いします。

```
/aaa/ --> http://www.example.com/aaa2/
/aaa/bbb/  --> http://www.example.com/aaa2/
```

### 環境

エックスサーバー×WordPress

### 試したこと

以下のコードをpublic_html直下の.htaccessに記述。階層が異なる301リダイレクトがうまくいっていません。
試したコード1

```
Redirect permanent /aaa/ http://www.example.com/aaa2/
Redirect permanent /aaa/bbb/ http://www.example.com/aaa2/
```

試したコード2

```
RedirectMatch 301 /aaa/(.*) http://www.example.com/aaa2/
RedirectMatch 301 /aaa/bbb/(.*) http://www.example.com/aaa2/
```

動作確認

```
/aaa/ --> http://www.example.com/aaa2/
/aaa/bbb/  --> http://www.example.com/aaa2/bbb/
```

Comment: 具体的にどのように上手く行っていないのですか？また、やりたいことがいまいち明確ではありません。質問文に記載の`試したコード2`だと1行目で`aaa`配下が全て`aaa2`にリダイレクトされるので2行目には到達しない気がします。末尾に`$1`のマッチした変数がついていないので`bbb`は継承されないと思いますが、301で試験したためブラウザがリダイレクトキャッシュしているのでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/aaa/bbb/` より先に  `/aaa/` がマッチされるので `/aaa/` の設定のほうが優先されて処理されてます。

設定ファイルで `/aaa/bbb/` を先に記述してみてください。

```
Redirect permanent /aaa/bbb/ http://www.page.com/aaa2/
Redirect permanent /aaa/ http://www.page.com/aaa2/
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。